# Do any Cassandra drivers for node.js support SSL?

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra

I am assuming the driver would need to support this.  If there is a way to 'force' SSL on the driver (without its knowledge) I'd appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this driver should support SSL in client-to-node communication:
https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver

Comment: Thanks Mateusz!  Noticed the 'official' driver from Datastax (released since I posted this) does support SSL.